# Rendering to a SWING surface (e. g. JPanel) using Cairo

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jpanel, cairo

I'm currently working on a project where I need to plot the predicted footprint of a satellite on a mercator-projected world map with possible scaling/cropping/etc. done to the map.

I thought Cairo would be a good library to use for this purpose. There are Java-bindings available for it. However, I just can't find a way to make it render onto a SWING GUI (e. g. onto the surface of a JPanel). I thought about rendering into a byte buffer and plotting it out pixel by pixel using Java2D, but I can't find any API call to make Cairo render into a buffer (which is weird, as this is one of the most fundamental functionalities I'd expect to get supported by such a library).

Any way I can achieve this? I know there is Java2D, but it is fairly basic. I'd really appreciate a more powerful, widespread, well-tested, high-quality, free (LGPL) graphics library for this purpose. Cairo would be such a perfect fit, if I could get it to work with SWING somehow.

Thank you very much for your proposals.

Comment: Generally, you use whatever component you want (e.g. JPanel), and call `.getGraphics()` to get a renderable `Graphics` object for that component. You then use that `Graphics` object to do the rendering. What have you already tried? Your question doesn't say what you've already attempted? Have you already gone through the tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)?

Comment: @normalocity: I would like to use Cairo (http://cairographics.org/) for the rendering itself, as it is much more powerful and much more convenient than the Java2D API. The API of the Java binding for Cairo is documented here: [link](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/freedesktop/cairo/package-summary.html) I just can't get it to render onto a SWING component (e. g. JPanel) or into a byte buffer. In the latter case, I could probably plot out the rasterized rendering, that Cairo created, using Java2D. But I just don't see any "render into buffer" functionality exposed by the API.

Comment: See also this [Java Map Projection Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fundamentals in Cairo is that any non-abstract image context is bound to one of the supported back ends.
I've never tried the Java bindings, but it is likely they are a thin layer, not providing a a new surface type - you should use the "Image Surface" type.

On the C documentation for the Library, there is a "cairo_image_surface_get_data()" call
(here: http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html ) which gives one acess to the buffer. 
Maybe the bindings didn't expose this to Java due to the low level memory access required to actually use its contents. If that is true, then I propose you the following work-around:

(1)Render your results to a Cairo Image Surface, (2) Write a temporary file with the surface contents,(3) Read and display the temporary file with the Java 2D API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [example](http://research.operationaldynamics.com/bzr/java-gnome/mainline/doc/examples/cairo/ExampleDrawingGradients.java). 
I found this examples on http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net
It create a gtk window, and actually a gtk DrawingArea widget, the onDraw() event uses cairo.
I compiled and run it on linux, it works good.

however java-gnome seems only have linux binary. Maybe somebody could make a windows binary, but need some work.

It is a gtk window, so have nothing to do with swing.
Maybe you don't need swing if gtk(java-gnome) can fit your needs.

If you must use swing, you can use cairo to render to a image in memory, then show it to JComponent by somthing like overriding paintComponent() method. I don't know the performance.